# How to process an uploaded file and notify the user later when the file is uploaded in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, web-development-server

I have a Django app that allows a user to upload file. I am processing this file on the server and it takes about 3 mins for the task to complete. I am assuming the browser won't wait that long for a response after POST request. So I want a way to respond to the post immediately after the file upload and start the heavy operation in a new thread and then 3 mins later notify the user.
Is this possible in Django and how? please do guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run a long running tasks, you can use Celery with Redis (or any other Celery Broker)
In this way, you can run a background task.

Now to notify a user about task completion, you can use [django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) or socket.io + redis or [djang-websocket](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-websocket)